# Wait function to finish, each loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout, each

So my goal is to have a set of `li` tags and iterate over them and for each `li` the hidden paragraph and then hide it and show the next `li` element. Once the iteration all done I want to repeat the process.

I already tried a callback function but it doesn't work, I think it is because setTimeout child thread's are independent from the main function. I don't want to use setInterval because I don't know how many *li* tags I'll have.

This is the js function:

```
function animateContents(){
    $('#test li').each(function(i){
        var a = this;

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(a).find('p').slideDown('slow', function(){
                $(this).addClass('in');
            }).delay(1000).slideUp('slow', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('in');
            });
        }, i*2500);
    });
}
```

This is the HTML code, for CSS I'm using Bootstrap:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<ul class="list-unstyled panel-group" id="test">
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title1</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title2</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title3</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title4</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title5</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-default">
        <h4 class="panel-heading panel-title">Title6</h4>
        <p class="panel-body collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias, asperiores aspernatur cupiditate dicta eaque impedit ipsum itaque laboriosam modi officiis perferendis provident quam quisquam, quod saepe sequi similique ut.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you capture this into a and then also use this instead of a? Also it appears to be working in my jsbin as is: http://jsbin.com/kiyub/1/edit?html,js,output Do you just want it to repeat?

Comment: Show us your callback approach.

Comment: Hi there. I use a to get the li childrens and this to get the p element.
Also the initial state should have all "p" hidden. 
And yes I just want animateContents to repeat over and over, forever. ;)

Comment: Please edit your question to add code - don't put code in comments. setInterval() doesn't care how many `li`'s you have.

Comment: How can I add a block of code here in the comment? Whats the tag? xD

Comment: @nobitta `animateContents` wrap your code with `-sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.Deferred` like all cool kids do :) http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/2Kdaq/

```
function animateContents(){
    var promises = $('#test li').map(function(i){
        var a = this, 
            dfd = $.Deferred(); //create a deferred

        console.log(i);

        $(a).find('p')
                .delay(i*2500) //instead of setTimeout
                .slideDown('slow', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('in');
                })
                .delay(1000)
                .slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('in');
                    dfd.resolve(); //resolve it
                });

        return dfd.promise(); //return a promise
    }).get();

    console.log(promises); 
    return $.when.apply($, promises); //make a promise that will wait for all
}

(function run() {
    animateContents().done(run); //loop forever   
}());
```

Comment: Ok, I want to understand why you don't use "each" nor "setTimeout"

Comment: `map` is more relevant if you want to get something from the loop. And I want to get promises. `setTimeout` is not necessary since we have `delay` method.

Comment: Ok but can I apply this `$.Deferred()` thing using `each` and `setTimeouts`?
With `each` and `setTimeout` the code is easier to read. 
I'll try add it :o

Comment: @nobitta sure you can. But I can't get how `setTimeout(function(){..}, i*2500)` is more readable than `.delay(i*2500)` :)

Answer (score 0):

@Yury Tarabanko already found a solution to my problem, but since I find promises/deferred a bit confusing I decided to dig a little bit more on my problem and I found a solution.

Here it is:

```
function animateB(elem){
    $(elem).find('p')
        .delay(500)
        .slideDown('slow', function(){
            $(this).addClass('in');
        })
        .delay(2500)
        .slideUp('slow', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('in');
            var n = $(elem).next('li');
            if(n.length == 0)
                n = $('#test li')[0];
            animateB(n);
        });
}

animateB($('#test li')[0]);
```

> Cheers